# Addressing a claim as a whole?

Tags: discussion

So I asked a question about a "documentary" shown on the BBC (back in 2007?), [that I just ran into on YouTube.](http://rbutr.com/http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJ-1iL9g8nU).  They are making a lot of claims that appear familiar, and was hoping someone would have a concise analysis of this film.  Do we ever address anything as a "whole" as opposed to the myriad of claims contained within a piece of propaganda?

Comment: What would it mean to address the "whole"? Does it just mean addressing each of the claims? If not, what else?

Comment: I was thinking that one could make some comments about the "documentary" as a whole: i.e. it deliberately misrepresents factual statements, uses cherry picking, etc. And then maybe some point by point?  Hey, I'm a newbie here, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A documentary can use cherry-picking, and be correct. It is a fallacy to assume that a statement is necessarily false *because* the evidence supporting it is poor.

A film can include multiple statements, and have some true and some false. It is a fallacy to assume that a statement is necessarily false *because* other claims from the same source have been proven to be false.

These situations may well trigger a higher-level skepticism, and a firmer expectation of quality evidence before provisionally accepting a claim as true, but they don't definitively determine the truth of a statement.

We are looking for definitive answers.

So, while this has "overall" approach has been tried in various questions in the past, they haven't been very successful.

Often questions have been closed as too broad because they point to an entire documentary or book and ask "Is this true?" To determine the truth-value of every single claim made in the average documentary would require a book-length answer.

Comment: I've seen a few answers that appear book length. ;)  Although I understand your point.